# How to change collection_name in spatie?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm a newbie in spatie. I have some trouble, I don't know how to change collection_name in spatie.

I select a record with collection_name is `enter code here` and change it to `doctor_avatar` and I do like:

```
$media = Media::where(['model_id' => $id, 'collection_name' => 'log_doctor_avatar'])->get();
$media->update([
'collection_name' => 'doctor_avatar',
]);
```

But have an error: `BadMethodCallException Method update does not exist.`

Can you help me solve this problem!

Comment: Do you want to change a collection name or do you want to move media from one collection to a different one?

Comment: I want to change collection name and  did it. But how can i move media from one collection to a different one? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that your variable $media is type Collection, and Collection does not have update method (as you can see in error message).

Try it like this:

```
$media = Media::where(['model_id' => $id, 'collection_name' => 'log_doctor_avatar'])->update(['collection_name' => 'doctor_avatar',]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.